# Enterprise Architect: Hide only some Foreign Key Labels to all connectors at once

Tags: database, database-design, enterprise-architect, database-diagramming, database-diagram

I am using Enterprise Architect 9 and I want do hide some Foreign Key Labels in all connectors, but not all.

I'm using Associate connector often, and when I set foreign keys, it shows some labels I do not want to see. I want to show numbers (Source and Target Bottom labels, but not Top) and Middle Bottom labels only.

I know I can right-click on it and select "Visibility"->"Set Label Visibility", and disable all I do not want, but I need to do it on each connector and I want to hide it by default for all other connectors too.

I know I can right-click on the diagram, select "Properties"->"Connectors" Tab and check the option "Suppress All Connector Labels". But it disables me all labels, what I do not want.

Is there some way to set which labels to show by default to all connectors at once?

Thanks for answers

P.S. I know, there is already a similar problem, but my problem is a little bit different, and that answer was not enough

Answer (score 0):

I've managed it using a shape script linked to the `<<FK>>` sterotype for the base class `association` in the Project->Settings->UML Types screen.

If you have a shape script like this:

```
shape LeftTopLabel { }

shape RightTopLabel { }

shape MiddleBottomLabel { }
```

then the label types you've overridden with an empty script will disappear, and the rest will remain.

Note that this will affect all diagrams in your project.

Comment: This no longer works in EA 16.1. EA uses `EAUML::FK` stereotype. In `UML Types` screen I see only `FK`, adding the script (or any other script) to it has no effect. I can't edit the Shape script for `EAUML::FK`. Do you have any solution for the current version?